# Search a text for specific text, then multiple if statements depending on what's there

Tags: google-sheets, worksheet-function, regex

I've got a weird question about Google Sheets.

First, here's what I've got so far, but it returns an error "Function REGEXEXTRACT parameter 2 value "My Text here" is not a valid regular expression."

```
=IF(REGEXEXTRACT(W8, $Y$1), SUBSTITUTE(W8,$Y$1, ""), 
 IF(REGEXEXTRACT(W8, $Y$2), SUBSTITUTE(W8,$Y$2, ""), 
    IF(REGEXEXTRACT(W8, $Y$3), SUBSTITUTE(W8,$Y$3, ""),
       IF(REGEXEXTRACT(W8, $Y$4), SUBSTITUTE(W8,$Y$4, ""), ""
                    )
     )
   )
)
```

Basically, what I want it to do, is check if a cell contains certain text, with different results based on what text it finds. I have 4 possibilities of what it could find, let's say it Looks for Abc, def, ghi, jkl in a line of text. When it sees abc, it looks at W8, and substitutes the matching text in W8 with $Y$1. If it sees def, it looks at W8, and substitutes the matching text in W8 with $Y$2. Etc. Etc. Etc. And then Ideally it shows as blank if it doesn't find any of those.

I feel like i'm really close to getting it right, but I just can't see it.

**Edit**

I've added the istext function to it, and it removes the error message, but now it's just returning a blank

```
=IF(ISTEXT(regexextract(W8, $Y$1)), SUBSTITUTE(W8,$Y$1, ""), 
 IF(ISTEXT(regexextract(W8, $Y$2)), SUBSTITUTE(W8,$Y$2, ""), 
    IF(ISTEXT(regexextract(W8, $Y$3)), SUBSTITUTE(W8,$Y$3, ""),
       IF(ISTEXT(regexextract(W8, $Y$4)), SUBSTITUTE(W8,$Y$4, ""), ""
                    )
     )
   )
```

**Edit 2**

For clarity's sake, I'm including what each of the cells I'm editing are:

W8: **Value:** `=SUBSTITUTE(C8,V8, "")`
       **Text:** `/slideshows/blah-blah.html?utm_source=naytev&utm_campaign=ab&utm_medium=cwpg&utm_term=paid`

$Y$2: `?utm_source=naytev&utm_campaign=ab&utm_medium=cwpg&utm_term=paid`

**EDIT 3**

I've condensed my problem down to one line, to further simplify the problem: `=IF(ISTEXT(REGEXMATCH(W8, $Y$2)), SUBSTITUTE(W8,$Y$2, ""), "00")` Returns 00

Answer (score 2):

## Short Answer

> W8: ... 
>   text `/slideshows/blah-blah.html?utm_source=naytev&utm_campaign=ab&utm_medium=cwpg&utm_term=paid`
>   $Y$2: `?utm_source=naytev&utm_campaign=ab&utm_medium=cwpg&utm_term=paid`

The formula doesn't work because, among other possible causes, the values of W8 and $Y$2 are't valid regular expressions. Both looks like parts of an URL and both include characters that in a regular expression have special meanings.

As was mentioned in a comment to this answer instead of regular expression functions you could use [FIND](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094126?hl=en) or [SEARCH](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094154?hl=en) as this could be the fasted (and easier?) solution to apply.

## Explanation

The initial error message implies that the value at least one of $Y$1, $Y$2, $Y$3, $Y$4 are not valid regular expressions.

From [REGEXEXTRACT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098244?hl=en)

> **Syntax**
>
> REGEXEXTRACT(text, regular_expression)
>
> text - The input text.
>
> regular_expression - The first part of text that matches this
>   expression will be returned.
>
> Notes
>
> - Google products use RE2 for [regular expressions](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/62754#regular_expression). Learn more on how to use [RE2 expressions](https://github.com/google/re2/blob/master/doc/syntax.txt).
> - This function only works with text (not numbers) as input and returns text as output. If a number is desired as the output, try
>     using the VALUE function in conjunction with this function. If numbers
>     are used as input, convert them to text using the TEXT function.

It's worth to note that when we are working with nested functions and a large formula doesn't work, a good practice is to test each part individually, in other words validate that the value or values of each argument of each function are valid and of the proper type.

H/T to an user that use to change their display name at any time who posted [this answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/113521/88163)

Comment: Yeah, I realized that regex doesn't like text much, so the ISTEXT fixed that, I think, it no longer produced an error, anyways. It's returning a blank now

Comment: @ChrisMcMahon The main take-away is that regular expressions have certain syntax in which, for example, ? has special meaning. If you are looking for substring search, use [`search`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094154?hl=en) or [`find`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094126), depending on whether case-sensitivity is needed. Wrap those in `if(iserror(find(...), ..., ...)` because they return an error if not found.

Answer (score 0):

The previous answers were right. Your regular expression contains vague characters like `?`, which would mean different things in regular expression. But,Fortunately , re2 supports literal text.

```
\Q...\E
```

Anything written between Q and E is taken literally.

If

A1:

```
/slideshows/blah-blah.html?utm_source=naytev&utm_campaign=ab&utm_medium=cwpg&utm_term=paid
```

A2:

```
?utm_source=naytev&utm_campaign=ab&utm_medium=cwpg&utm_term=paid
```

A3:

```
=IF(REGEXMATCH(A1,"\Q"&A2&"\E"),SUBSTITUTE(A1, A2,""))
```

A3 Value: `/slideshows/blah-blah.html`